# My emulator is taking up too much memory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

As per the title, my Android Studio seems to be using too much memory, even at idle. For my friend, he is able to run his emulator at only ~300MB of RAM usage, according to Windows' Task Manager. I've tried duplicating his emulator settings, even with his emulator set to 1.5GB of RAM, it is only using about 300MB. Mine goes up to 1.5GB, sometimes even 2GB, just by getting it started, I'm not even running any apps on it.

Is this even possible? Running it at only ~300MB, because on mine, the lowest I can go is 1024MB, setting anything lower results in no change in Task Manager.

Comment: Memory consumption depends also about the project you load in the IDE, also plugins and open files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the installation process you installed more things than him. That's why it's eating a lot more memory

Comment: During the installation of Android Studio?

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling, no difference.

Comment: Upon installation did you uncheck most of resources? If yes, I don't know what the problem is.